# Random Numbers and Pathos Multiprocessing

Tags: python, random, multiprocessing

I was wondering if there were a recommended way of using the parallel map feature in `pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessPool` for functions that involve random number generation, *i.e.*,

```
def f(x):
    return x*np.random.rand()

pool = pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessPool(nodes=4)

results = pool.map(f,np.linspace(0,1,11))
```

I suspect I could do something simple like add `np.random.seed()` to the `f` function, but I would, ideally, like some reproducibility. Is there a way to just assign a different, known, seed to each of the workers in the pool and then execute the mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NumPy documentation includes an example of how multiple processes can be used to reduce the time to generate random numbers.

[Multithreaded Generation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/multithreading.html).

Essentially, you assign each process a different PRNG, initialized based on a common seed, divide an array into chunks, assign each chunk to a process, and have each process fill its assigned chunk with random numbers.  The example (at the time of this writing) uses PCG and jumps the PRNG ahead to form different streams of numbers for each process.  (See "[Parallel Random Number Generation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/parallel.html)" for the different ways random number streams are supported in NumPy.  See also my section "[Seeding Multiple Processes](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Seeding_Multiple_Processes)".)